# Conditionally convergent series value

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Find all values of $p$ such that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^j\cdot\log(j)}{j^p}$ is conditionally convergent.

I know that the alternating series test states that if a series has the form $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ja_j$ where $a_j$ is a positive sequence that decreases monotonically to zero, then the series is convergent if and only if $a_{j+1} \leq a_j$ for all $j$ and $\lim_{j \to \infty}a_j = 0$.

So from that, I think that in this case, we have $a_j = \frac{\log(j)}{j^p}$. To satisfy the conditions of the alternating series test, we need to ensure that $a_{j+1} \leq a_j$ for all $j$ and $\lim_{j \to \infty}a_j = 0$. But I'm not sure if this is correct, and I anyways am unsure of how I can continue the problem from there. Can someone help me?

Comment: If the sign is alternating, you only need the magnitude monotonically decreasing after a certain point, i.e. for all $j >n_0$ for some $n_0$ as well as $\lim_{j \to \infty}a_j = 0$.

Comment: Sorry but what is the $n_0$ and how can we find that?

Comment: It is an arbitrary point which may depend on $p$.  For example, with $p=1$ then $\frac{\log(2)}{2^1} \approx 0.151 < 0.159 \approx \frac{\log(3)}{3^1}$ but for all $j\ge 3$ you have  $\frac{\log(j)}{j} > \frac{\log(j+1)}{(j+1)}$ and you will be able to apply the alternating series test. You do not need to find $n_0$ exactly, but you need to show it exists, possibly by finding a value which is more than big enough

Comment: Ohhh I see. So now I just set the limit of the function to 0 and solve for $p$? I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: That is a good place to start as you need a limit of $0$. Then try to show whether for those $p$ you have alternating and magnitude eventually  monotonically decreasing.

Comment: I got that $p$ can be any number in the interval $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: Indeed that will give $\frac{\log(j)}{j^p} \to 0$.  And if you differentiate $\frac{\log(j)}{j^p}$ with respect to $j$ then you can find any $n_0> e^{1/p}$ will do so $(0,\infty)$ works for the original question

Comment: Hmm, but I did submit $(0, \infty)$ as my submission but it apparently was an incorrect answer.

Comment: Perhaps consider which $p$s would give absolute convergence and exclude them from those giving conditional convergence.  Possibly the answer is then $(0,1]$

Comment: Ohhhhh I disregarded that, I get it now, thank you so much for the help!